# Getting Error in Endpoint While Running A WCF REST Service

Tags: wcf, rest

I'm developing a REST service using WebHttpBinding.
Everything is perfect in my service, but while running it gives `Error Endpoint not Found`.

The web.config File is like this:

```
 <configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Service">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:10492/Service.svc" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IService" behaviorConfiguration="webby"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webby">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>

  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

In address I tried like this also:

```
<endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IService" behaviorConfiguration="webby"/>
```

But it's still not working.

Comment: Fur future reference, please list all files that you have in your project relating to this service, what address you are attempting to locate your service on, and *how* you are attempting to locate your service (application, WCF test client, web browser etc).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good link to get you started: http://weblogs.asp.net/kiyoshi/archive/2008/10/08/wcf-using-webhttpbinding-for-rest-services.aspx

On what address are you attempting to connect to your web service? (Have you tried navigating to the address in your web browser, and what URL did you type in?)

[EDIT]

Being that you are hosting in a web application, IIS (or whatever web server you are using) will expect that a service descriptor file exists for your service. You cannot just create a URI in the web.config, and host it in IIS without an associated 'service' file on the file-system (this is your Service1.svc file).

**This is a nuance specific to hosting WCF services within Internet Information Services - it is easy to forget about this step, if you are reading tutorials designed for self-hosted scenarios.**

Make sure that you have a file in your website called "Service1.svc" and it should contain something like this:

```
<%@ServiceHost Language="C#" Service="MyNamespace.Service1" Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory" %>
```

Here is a tutorial on hosting REST services within IIS: http://saravananarumugam.wordpress.com/2011/03/04/simple-rest-implementation-with-webhttpbinding/

Another concern that jumps out at me, is that your endpoint address you have defined ("http://localhost:10492/Service.svc") does not conform to REST conventions. I wouldnt expect this would be your problem, but it is A problem.